# JENKINS ERROR: Echec à la lecture des POMs java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

please i have this error in my project after BUILD SUCCESS of project and Junit Test i get this error :

after cmd mvn test the build is SUCCESS

then jenkins recupered the data

ERROR: Failure in the reading of POMs java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/testjunit/trunk/pom.xml

```
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] trunk 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ............................... SUCCESS [  0.025 s]
[INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  6.979 s]
[INFO] SmartFix ........................................... SUCCESS [  9.610 s]
[INFO] bouygues ........................................... SUCCESS [ 42.949 s]
[INFO] oasis .............................................. SUCCESS [  6.709 s]
[INFO] Schneider .......................................... SUCCESS [  2.784 s]
[INFO] Samsung ............................................ SUCCESS [  7.661 s]
[INFO] Sermicro ........................................... SUCCESS [  6.207 s]
[INFO] Pm2s ............................................... SUCCESS [  6.354 s]
[INFO] Monitoring ......................................... SUCCESS [  5.976 s]
[INFO] core_ws ............................................ SUCCESS [  4.308 s]
[INFO] Securitas .......................................... SUCCESS [  4.359 s]
[INFO] Tango .............................................. SUCCESS [  6.819 s]
[INFO] Monitoring_lux 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ...................... SUCCESS [  2.752 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 02:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-08-17T11:22:17+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
En attente que Jenkins finisse de récupérer les données
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/bouygues/pom.xml to fr.pc30/bouygues/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bouygues-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/bouygues/target/pc30.jar to fr.pc30/bouygues/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bouygues-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/core/pom.xml to fr.pc30/core/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/pom.xml to fr/trunk/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/trunk-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
/root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/pom.xml is not inside /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/testjunit/trunk/; will archive in a separate pass
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Schneider/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Schneider/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Schneider-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Monitoring_lux/pom.xml to fr/Monitoring_lux/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Monitoring_lux-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/oasis/pom.xml to fr/oasis/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/oasis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/oasis/target/oasis.jar to fr/oasis/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/oasis-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Tango/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Tango/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Tango-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Tango/target/Tango.jar to fr.pc30/Tango/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Tango-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Sermicro/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Sermicro/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Sermicro-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Pm2s/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Pm2s/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Pm2s-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Pm2s/target/Pm2s.jar to fr.pc30/Pm2s/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Pm2s-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/core_ws/pom.xml to fr.pc30/core_ws/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/core_ws-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Securitas/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Securitas/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Securitas-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/SmartFix/pom.xml to fr.pc30/SmartFix/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SmartFix-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/SmartFix/target/smartFix.jar to fr.pc30/SmartFix/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/SmartFix-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Monitoring/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Monitoring/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Monitoring-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Samsung/pom.xml to fr.pc30/Samsung/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Samsung-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/trunk/Samsung/target/samsung_I-GSPN.jar to fr.pc30/Samsung/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Samsung-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war
ERROR: Echec à la lecture des POMs
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/testjunit/trunk/pom.xml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1887)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.properties.PomPropertiesFinder.findProperties(PomPropertiesFinder.java:50)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoExtractor.extract(MavenInfoExtractor.java:58)
    at jenkins.plugins.maveninfo.extractor.MavenInfoEnvironment.tearDown(MavenInfoEnvironment.java:42)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:908)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1794)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
channel stopped
```

[image: picture of error]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry, but this is unreadable. Please paste it as text. Also english would be preferred ;-)

Comment: so any answer ?

Comment: It says "NoSuchFileException: /root/.jenkins/workspace/testjunit/testjunit/trunk/pom.xml". Seems it needs a pom.xml there. Where is it?

Comment: Seems the directory `testjunit/` is duplicated within the path.

Comment: my pom in right directory but it still have the same error